# LSTM model doesn't predict values higher than certain value (not same value all the time)

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

First of all thanks for any help!

I want to create a simple LSTM model that predict the value of next minute Household Electric Power Consumption. using this dataset:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/individual+household+electric+power+consumption

What I've done so far is:

1) normalize the data and created a "window" that makes my LSTM network look like this:
[image]

Series of 30 minutes from t0-t29 with 8 features in each minute, and the network should output the t30 house electric power consumption. 
Therefore my each sample input is in a shape of [30x8] and output should be [1x1]. so far, so good.

2) I've build a simple LSTM model that looks like this:

```
model4 = Sequential()
model4.add(LSTM(1,input_shape=(30, 8)))
model4.add(Dense(1))
model4.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

As you can see, a very simple many to one model. I've trained the model for 25 epochs and for some reason the model doesn't seem to predict value higher than 5-5.5 as you can see in this graph:
[image: Predictions vs. actual]

3) I've tried to:

- normalize the data differently (min max or mean std)
- normalize all data but the column of the power consumption i kept with it original values.
  None of the above helped.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

i changed to property "activation" of the LSTM layer to None.
this way the values were not "smashed" by the default "tanh" function.

Comment: I get the same problem, however when I change the activation=None, the LSTM takes around 100x more time for each epoch. What did you do?